# Problem with Knife tool and Industry Compatible keymap

Tags: modeling

I am using   Industry Compatible keymap , and when I use the knife tool, I can't rotate the object, and I continuously cut the thing... can we address this somewhere or somehow?

Comment: Yes you need to press Enter to validate before being able to rotate, I don't know if you can avoid that

Comment: Hi. I hope you don't mind my edit. The keymap has a [specific name](https://imgur.com/qJOMKmY) in the user preferences and there is no reason not to use it. Hopefully that is a bit clearer.

Comment: Knife tool actually works fine with all navigation controls while in operation in Blender 3.4.1 with default keymap as well as Industry Compatible when I test it. What's the version you are using? What OS, what pointing/navigation device?

Comment: uuu sounds cool, I am using versio 3.4

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys no it doesnt work, I am suing alt to rotate objects

Comment: As is, the Industry Compatible Keymap doesn't prevent you to navigate while using the knife tool, so it must be something else. Do you have the [Emulate 3 Button Mouse](https://i.imgur.com/IUp2IJy.png) option enabled?

Comment: @Shliosas "no it doesn't work" - I am not saying it does work for you. I am saying it definitely works for me when I test it with Blender reset to "factory settings". I can navigate 3d scene when I start cutting an object with the knife tool before I finish the operation with default keymap and when I set it to Industry Compatible as well. That's a fact. It should help with narrowing down where the issue may be.

Comment: When you say you cannot rotate the object, do you mean you cannot navigate around it, or actually change object's rotation with rotate operation?

Comment: I cant navigate around it